# Do JS function if window width between 800px and 799px

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, responsive, between

I've written this simple code to reload the page on resize when the window is between 799 and 800px but it doensn't work, does anyone know why?

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
  if ( $(window).width() > 799 && $(window).width() < 800 {
    location.reload();
  } else {}
});
```

I've also written this code to check if the width is under 800 after the page reloads to do some stuff

```
if ($(window).width() < 800) {
  // do some stuff
} else {}
```

I probably could also use a function which should just toggle once if the breakpoints (f.ex.: 800px) gets hitted, any ideas?

Comment: Your browser probably only gives integer width values. There are no integers between 799 and 800.

Comment: Do you think a number of pixels exists strictly less than 800 and strictly greater than 799?

Comment: `799 +1 =  800.` 1 pixel while resizing? Not-possible because no on resizing pixel by pixel

Comment: I thought it could work that the function triggers while I'am resizing, lets say I'am resizing the window and if it gets under 800 it should trigger a function but only once, I dont know how to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
var ww = $(window).width();
var limit = 800;
function refresh() {
   ww = $(window).width();
   var w =  ww<limit ? (location.reload(true)) :  ( ww>limit ? (location.reload(true)) : ww=limit );
}
var tOut;
$(window).resize(function() {
    var resW = $(window).width();
    clearTimeout(tOut);
    if ( (ww>limit && resW<limit) || (ww<limit && resW>limit) ) {
        tOut = setTimeout(refresh, 10);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `>=` and `<=` instead of just `>` and `<`, like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ( $(window).width() >= 799 && $(window).width() <= 800 {
    location.reload();
  } else {}
});
```

`> 799 && < 800` will never fires, because there is no integers between 799 and 800.

Comment: *like this* ..  :/ take your time and write proper answers.

Comment: Sorry guys, i just misspelled. I have updated the answer